# How to use 3rd Party Shader with LWRP / URP

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have converted my project to use Lightweight Render Pipeline, all materials get converted to use LWRP but materials that support 3rd party shaders, for those what I require to do?

For example, Water Wiggle shader that I have used in my project.
[image]

So how to convert this shader into LWRP? or how can I use it in the original form?
Currently, it becomes pink as you see in the above image.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.lightweight@5.10/manual/getting-started-with-lwrp.html): `Note: Projects made using LWRP are not compatible with the High Definition Render Pipeline or the built-in Unity rendering pipeline. This is because the three render pipelines use different lighting models. Before you start development, you must decide which render pipeline to use in your Project.`

Comment: and `Note: Built-in and custom Lit Shaders do not work with the Lightweight Render Pipeline. Instead, LWRP has a new set of standard shaders. If you upgrade a current Project to LWRP, you can upgrade built-in shaders to the new ones.`

Comment: But how to deal with custom shaders?

Comment: Please add the shader code.